# How can I add the Line2D object to the figure in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D   

line = plt.Line2D([1], [1])
plt.show() #it's doing nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to draw a straight line? Or are you trying to plot a straight line?

To just plot a straight line do:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
plt.show()
```

Output

[image]
If you are set on using Line2D then you can do something like this, your problem is that you need more than 1 value for x or y in the line 2D (1 x value and 1 y value just makes a point):

```py
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D   

x = [0,1,2,3,4]
y = [1]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
line = Line2D(x, y)
ax.add_line(line)
plt.xlim(min(x), max(x))
plt.ylim(0, 2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Stop deleting my comments while I am trying to teach new users. (Not directed at you OP)   [Asking users to accept answer when they comment that it answers their question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/asking-users-to-accept-answer-when-they-comment-that-it-answers-their-question) | [Asking for someone to accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer) | [Teaching new users how to accept an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354584/teaching-new-users-how-to-accept-an-answer)